# Help on regular expression

Tags: regex, r

Using [rSymPy](http://code.google.com/p/rsympy/) to solve a system of equations, I got the values of x and y that solve the system in a character string like this:

```
"[(1.33738072607023, 27.9489435205271)]"
```

How should i assign those 2 values to variables x, y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To split the string, you can use:

```
vect <- as.numeric(strsplit(gsub("[^[:digit:]\\. \\s]","",x)," "))
x <- vect[1]
y <- vect[2]
```

This deletes everything that is not a space, a point or a digit. strsplit splits the string that's left in a vector. See also the related help files.

Assignment can be done in a loop or using Gavin's function. I'd just name them.

```
names(vect) <-c("x","y")
vect["x"]
       x 
1.337381
```

For bigger datasets, I like to keep things together to avoid overloading the workspace with names.

Comment: @Joris, you could `assign` into another environment and attach it, which has the effect of keeping global environment clean but allowing direct access to the objects.

Comment: for assigning some x and y, that seems very much overkill. And indeed, one could start playing around with environments, but personally I prefer lists. Does exactly the same, goes a bit faster and gives less headaches debugging. YMMV

Comment: @Joris that was in response to the "bigger datasets" line; agree it is overkill for @Brani's example. I too like lists, but you still have to index into the list to access the components or use `with()`, unless you attach it...

Comment: @Gavin: in this case even a named vector would suffice. Environments I find useful if I have very different and complex objects I'd like to keep together. But otherwise I've done fine with lists. You have to tell R from which environment you want an object as well, and then I believe indexing works a bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some steps that will do what you want to do. Can't say it is the most efficient or elegant solution available...

```
string <- "[(1.33738072607023, 27.9489435205271)]"
string <- gsub("[^[:digit:]\\. \\s]", "", string)
splt <- strsplit(string, " ")[[1]]
names(splt) <- c("x","y")
FOO <- function(name, strings) {
    assign(name, as.numeric(strings[name]), globalenv())
    invisible()
}
lapply(c("x","y"), FOO, strings = splt)
```

The last line would return:

```
> lapply(c("x","y"), FOO, strings = splt)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

And we have `x` and `y` assigned in the global environment

```
> x
[1] 1.337381
> y
[1] 27.94894
```

Answer (score 2):

`strapply` in the gsubfn package makes it fairly easy to extract numbers from strings using only a relatively simple regexp.  Here `s` is the input string and `v` is a numeric vector with the two numbers:

```
library(gsubfn)
v <- strapply(s, "[0-9.]+", as.numeric)[[1]]
x <- v[1]
y <- v[2]
```